# Cannot resolve android google map imports - OverlayController and Point

Tags: java, android, google-maps

While I am trying to compile and run a program Friend Finder, which I got from this [link](http://www.anddev.org/map-tutorials-f18/the-friend-finder-mapactivity-using-gps-full-source-t87.html), I ran into many compilation errors. I know that the code will not work without modification for the target android-sdk 2.2 , because it is an old project and also targeting android sdk 1.0.

Now, my problem lies in resolving these two imports:

```
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayController;
import com.google.android.maps.Point;
```

Also I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

I opened map.jar from the package explorer on Eclipse, and I cannot find those two classes on that jar too. That makes me think that those two classes are removed from the map API, but i cannot find that saying on internet. So, what happened to these two classes or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sample application is from 2007, from the earliest beta (M3) of the Android SDK. That code will no longer work on Android -- it hasn't worked in three years.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and now I found link to an updated version of the same application, that I can made work with little modifications. Here is the [link](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=10555#10555) for who needs it in future.